# How to avoid an opened Comport if it is already opened

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm using following code to send sms throuh gsm modem

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            MSComm1.CommPort = 3;
            MSComm1.PortOpen = true;
            MSComm1.Output = "AT" + '\r' + '\n';
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            MSComm1.Output = "AT+CMGF=1" + '\r' + '\n';
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            MSComm1.Output = "AT+CMGS=" + '\"' + MobileNo + '\"' + '\r' + '\n';
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            MSComm1.Output = MsgTxt + (char)26;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            MSComm1.PortOpen = false;
        }
```

my question is: 
i want to open the port as in (MSComm1.CommPort = 3;) only if it is not already opened. so that i don't have to open and close it again and again for each sms as in the above loop

Comment: Surely you must have considered a simple bool variable to keep track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ditch the MSComm ActiveX control if you're using any language/framework designed in the last decade or if you'd like your application to run on new or newer machines/Operating Systems.

Instead you can use the [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30swa673.aspx) class provided in the .Net Framework:

```
using (var com3 = new SerialPort("COM3"))
{
    if (!com3.IsOpen) com3.Open();

    for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ++ii)
    {
        com3.WriteLine("AT" + Environment.NewLine);
        com3.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + Environment.NewLine);
        com3.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=\"" + 03152800485 + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);
        com3.WriteLine("Hello Kashif" + (char)26);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
    com3.Close();
}
```

Comment: This is something new and quite different than what i was using to send sms. i will try this.. will i not have to use system.threading to wait after every WriteLine in this case???

Comment: Coding from sixletter had some problems and thus i've edited it

Comment: Anyways you made me learn something new. I really didn't know that even without using MSComm32 the sms could be sent

Comment: You're welcome! Some minor points: you don't have to close `com3` if you keep it in a `using`-statement. Also it seems odd that you need to sleep, perhaps data is being sent back to you and you should read from `com3`.

Comment: I did't get your point. I don't need to sleep and data is being sent to me??? if i don't sleep only one sms is sent i do have to sleep.. and what type of data is being sent to me.. can you plzz elaborate?

Comment: I'm just wondering if `com3.BytesToRead > 0` after your last `WriteLine`.